# Spring boot workflow submodule activiti permissions issue

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to download the sample and play with it. This is exactly what I was trying to do for one of my clients.

However I am not able to run the sample app. I get error when I try to update the submodule

git submodule update
Cloning into 'activiti'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '*' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'git@github.com:jbarrez/Activiti.git' into submodule path 'activiti' failed

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind its a git permissions issues

config change from git@ to https worked.